# Get public ip address in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ip

I'm looking for a simple function (as simple as it can be) for returning the public ip address.
I came across this function:

```
const clientsIpAdress = (onNewIP) => {
  const MyPeerConnection =
    window.RTCPeerConnection ||
    window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
    window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  const pc = new MyPeerConnection({
    iceServers: []
  });
  const noop = () => {};
  const localIPs = {};
  const ipRegex =
    /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g;

  const iterateIP = (ip) => {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  };
  pc.createDataChannel('');
  pc.createOffer().then((sdp) => {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach((line) => {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    });

    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  });
  pc.onicecandidate = (ice) => {
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate ||
      !ice.candidate.candidate ||
      !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
  };
};
export default clientsIpAddress;
```

but it is returning the local ipAddress. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use another source to determine that address. The local machine generally has no knowledge of the public address.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm new to javascript and i must complete this task. Can you provide me a guideline?

Comment: You may want to perform an HTTP request to ipify: https://api.ipify.org/

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't answer this, as I don't know how to do it... I just know the networking side :) Seems you have an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.ip);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Excuse me i made an awfull mistake. I want the public ip not the local. I wrote this in my description but not in the Title :P

Comment: ohh i see, Wait  a minute i am going to edit my answer.

Comment: You can approve if it is useful to you ! @user7334203

Comment: Can you write this in es6?

Comment: Yes it's works, just you have to enable "allow block script" from your browser in case it is not working.

Comment: Yes that's why i accept it! Thank you but what about in es6? Should we transform it into promise?

Comment: I have ES10 in my machine. if you have older one then try it. i am not sure hopefully that might be worked their also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142730/discussion-between-divyesh-gausvami-and-user7334203).